# Performance Problem in .Net compact framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

I cant understand why sending parameters to insert function works slow in .net compact framework.

Forexample following code inserts within 2 seconds

```
    cn = New SqlCeConnection(strstring)
    cmd = New SqlCeCommand
    Dim rs As SqlCeResultSet
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
    cn.Open()
    Dim rec As SqlCeUpdatableRecord
    Dim DB As New Db
    Dim a As Integer = 1
    Dim b As Integer = 2
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
        If i = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "A"
            rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable)
            rec = rs.CreateRecord()
        End If
        Try
            rec.SetValue(0, a)
            rec.SetValue(1, b)
            rs.Insert(rec
         Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    Next
```

But when i send parameters, a and b,to a insert sub,this code completes within 13 seconds.What does performance decrease?

```
 cn = New SqlCeConnection(strstring)
    cmd = New SqlCeCommand
    Dim rs As SqlCeResultSet
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
    cn.Open()
    Dim rec As SqlCeUpdatableRecord

    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
        If i = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "A"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
            rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable)
            rec = rs.CreateRecord()
        End If
        Try
            DB.Insert(1, 2, rs, rec)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    Next
```

This is insert sub in db class

Public Class Db

```
Public Shared Sub Insert(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer, ByRef rs As SqlCeResultSet, ByRef rec As SqlCeUpdatableRecord)
    Try
        rec.SetValue(0, a)
        rec.SetValue(1, If(b = String.Empty, DirectCast(DBNull.Value, Object), b))
        rs.Insert(rec)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```

end class

Comment: 2 integer copies to the stack?

Comment: Break out a profiler and see?

Comment: Have you checked that one of them isn't throwing an exception?

Comment: no exception and using try catch doesnt decrease.i guess 2 integer to the stack can make slow,how can i prevent it?When i assing integer as nothing,it doesnt change.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to have empty try/catch in your code. Can you remove them and test again?

Comment: ok,it was cause of error.I didnt see error,now i see.Try catch didnt influence,converting string to double creates error.Now no problem.Thanks.

Comment: how long does it take to execute if you used a SqlCeCommand to perform the insert/updates?

Comment: Try catch might not have influenced, but it hid the error... that's why it's a really bad idea to have empty catch blocks ;-)

Comment: Closing as "No longer Relevant"

Answer (score 0):

I would check your installation carefully on the device. It's quite easy to get it mixed up. The new way to google for the product is SQL Server Compact.

As microsoft decides to change the name of everything in the mobile/CE space, it makes it impossible to search for help. Is it Windows CE, or Pocket PC, or Windows Mobile, or Phone 7? Is it SQL CE or Sql Server Compact "Arrgh"!

Maybe these links will help the next guy. [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laxmi/archive/2009/10/07/sql-ce-binaries-details.aspx) or this one [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/75369a11-cf8b-4689-8f89-bcb9a2422c1c).